# How can I reset the startup directory to my HOME in Fish?

Tags: shell, fish

In my desktop manager, I have bound `fish` to a keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>~</kbd>. On startup, `fish` opens the directory `/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm`. This is quite annoying, because I have no business with lightdm, and I usually work on code in my `$HOME` directory.

How can I change the directory that fish starts in? I would like to change the startup directory simply to `~/`

Answer (score 11):

I had found that the `config.fish` file that runs at startup had been changing my default working directory.

A misguided attempt at setting my `PATH` left a list of directories in my `config.fish`, the first of which was `/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm`. Fish automatically assumes directories without a command should be `cd``d into, so my shell was `cd``ing into that directory at startup.

I removed the stray lines and all is well.

**To change your fish startup directory:**
add `cd /path/to/new/startup/directory` to your `~/.config/fish/config.fish` file, or create it if it does not exist.

Comment: No, don't do it! If you add a `cd` to your `config.fish`, it will work for everyday use, but `fish` will also run the `cd` before you run any Fish shell script. So if you try to run the script with a path relative to your current directory, like `fish hello.fish` or `./hello.fish`, then you will get an error like “hello.fish: No such file or directory” unless you are already in the custom directory you specified.

Comment: I want to strongly emphasize what codysehl said, DON'T DO THAT; executing cd before every shell command by adding it to config.fish lead to a ton of problems (vifm got messed really bad for example). I learned it the hard way..

Comment: Can someone provide a better answer, if this one ins wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55730891/7683365 is the correct answer which doesn't affect your scripts or any shell command call from another program.

Answer (score 7):

As @nathaniel-waisbrot says in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47624544/7232773), you can `cd` only when running fish interactively (the shell not the scripts):

```
# ~/.config/fish/config.fish

if status is-interactive
  cd $HOME
end
```

Using fish's `status` command

If that doesn't do it for you, it might be your fish theme. I use the [dangerous theme](https://github.com/oh-my-fish/theme-dangerous) which has [a bookmarking feature](https://github.com/oh-my-fish/theme-dangerous#bookmarks). Removing the bookmark from my startup directory solved this problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

*While not directly related to OP's question it is close enough that my search turned up this thread. So I'm sharing this answer for the other searchers.*

iTerm will store the path (along with tabs, tab titles, and window layout) under its "Arrangements" tab. Apparently when I set my default arrangement I had a single tab open to `/`.

I was able to change this to whatever I want by `cd`ing to my home directory and changing my default window arrangement.

I imagine if you had no default arrangement the "Reuse previous session's directory" option would work for new sessions but it does not work for restored arrangements.